# upgrading vanilla EE from 2.5.3 to 2.6.0 Fatal error: Call to undefined function function_usable()

Tags: email

Help!

I upgraded to 2.6, with no issues during the upgrade process. I can see my site fine. When I try to login to the control panel, I am able to see and use the authentication (username and password), but then see this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function function_usable() in (path here)/system/codeigniter/system/libraries/Email.php on line 1761

Any ideas or suggestions to fix?

Warmly,

Bill

Answer (score 1):

looks like this is a known bug that is due to be fixed in next release.

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19326